# sparse matrix memory

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix

I need to implement a sparse matrix as efficiently memory-wise as I can in Java.I receive a matrix with more 0 than other values and I need to save it efficiently.I was thinking of using an array with an Object containing value and position composed of the line*max nr of columns+the column.

Comment: Would a `Map` not be suitable?

Comment: i thought something like that.I want to know the best way memory-wise to save a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends entirely on what operations you are doing on said matrix which implementation will suit your needs.

e.g. if all you are doing is updating values and retrieving them a `Map<Point, Value>` will work.
Addition is also easy in this, but multiplication becomes very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

A Guava [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) can be sparse.

The [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html) library also has sparse matrices.